# Can busybox expand anonymous subshell output into anonymous file operands like bash can?

Tags: bash, unix, busybox

In bash it works:

```
diff <(echo foo) <(echo bar)
1c1
< foo
---
> bar
```

In busybox it doesn't.

Busybox says they pay attention to the SUSv3 standard; does SUSv3 provide a way? Lot's of test code uses such tricks to examine command output without having to create temporary files. Or could I at least say such tricks are not standards compliant?

Comment: Process substitution `<(...)` is not in any standard

Answer (score 2):

The `<(...)` is called *process substitution* and is a feature of bash. Busybox doesn't support it.

Comment: I agree it doesn't support it, but what to do with these test scripts to fix them?

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
[ -p /tmp/f1 ] || mkfifo /tmp/f1
[ -p /tmp/f2 ] || mkfifo /tmp/f2
echo foo >> /tmp/f1 &
echo bar >> /tmp/f2 &
diff /tmp/f1 /tmp/f2
1c1
< foo
---
> bar
```

### EDIT

Check if pipes exist

Comment: What about the second time I run the script and `mkfifo /tmp/f1` fails with `mkfifo: cannot create fifo 'f1': File exists`? The nice thing about piping things around is no need to worry about cleanup.